# dynamic props for svelte component

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have a svelte component that receives two props: `value` and `multiple`. `multiple` has `boolean` type, and `value`'s type depends on whether `multiple` is `true` or `false`. If I used these props in a function I would do something like:

```js
interface Single {
  multiple: false;
  value: string | null
};

interface Multiple {
  multiple: true;
  value: string[] | [];
};

const doSomenthing = (props: Single | Multiple) => {};
```

Typescript would complain if I try to call the function with:

```js
doSomething({ multiple: false, value: ['hello', 'world'] })
```

So far, I haven't figured the way of doing the same thing on svelte, so that if I instantiate the component:

```html
<MyComponent multiple={false} value={['hello', 'world']} />
```

throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can come up with is to type the `$$Props` generally, note that you would still have to type the exports individually with all possibilities as well. Meaning this is not perfect either because internally the type of value can be all four.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    type Multiple = { multiple: true; value: string[] | [] };
    type Single = { multiple: false; value: string | null };
    type $$Props = Multiple | Single;

    export let multiple: boolean;
    export let value: string | string[] | [] | null;
</script>

{#if multiple}
    {#each value as item}a{/each}
{:else}
    {#each value as item}a{/each}
{/if}
```

the above code will give errors when *using* the component wrong as you requested, but it will also give errors on the `#each` block because `null` is not an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're asking for setting the props seperately

```
<MyComponent multiple={false} value={['hello', 'world']} />
```

but why not export one prop and use  [ComponentProps](https://svelte.dev/docs/typescript#types-componentprops) to check for the correct type - [REPL](https://www.sveltelab.dev/h4s5fx42a7hy6kv)

###### Comp.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    
    interface Single {
        multiple: false;
        value: string | null;
    }

    interface Multiple {
        multiple: true;
        value: string[] | [];
    }

    export let singleOrMultiple: Single | Multiple;
    
</script>

Comp - {singleOrMultiple.multiple} {singleOrMultiple.value}
```

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Comp from '$lib/Comp.svelte';
    import type { ComponentProps } from 'svelte';

    const props: ComponentProps<Comp> = {
        singleOrMultiple: { multiple: false, value: null }
    };
    
</script>

<Comp {...props} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use one generic parameter for `multiple` to make value dependent on it:

```html
<script lang="ts" generics="T extends boolean">
    export let multiple: T;
    export let value: T extends true ? string[] : string;
</script>
```

(Note that generics syntax is not finalized. [RFC](https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/pull/38) - [Feedback thread](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/442))

Unfortunately `{#if multiple}` will currently not narrow the type of `value` correctly. So maybe it would be better to just drop `multiple` altogether and just use `Array.isArray(value)` in its place.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let value: string[] | string;
</script>

{#if Array.isArray(value)}
    {value.join(', ')}
{:else}
    {value}
{/if}
```